# Using a constant in an array created as part of a structure (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I am currently attempting to create a buffer that holds data that will later be passed via out the system via a output interface. This interface accepts up to 256 bytes of data. The goal of this data structure is the following:

- The array needs to be readable in its entirety from a single pointer. (In this case Buffer start)
- It should have a fixed number of header bits that will lead every buffer. (This is the part I am struggling on)
- You should be able to add data to the structure without indexing (using the buffer_current)
- You should be able to tell if the buffer if full quickly (comparing buffer_current with buffer end)

Below is my code.

```
    typedef struct
    {
        int TT1;
        int TT2;
        int Source;
        int Data;
    } Captured_data;

    typedef struct
    {
        void *Buffer_start;
        void *Buffer_current;
        void *Buffer_end;
    } Message_buffer;

void MB_init(Message_buffer *Message_buffer, int Elements)
        {
            Message_buffer -> Buffer_start = (Captured_data *)malloc(sizeof(Captured_data)*Elements+2);
            Message_buffer -> Buffer_current = Message_buffer -> Buffer_start+2;
            Message_buffer -> Buffer_end = Message_buffer + sizeof(Captured_data)*Elements+2;
        }
```

I want to add 2 bytes to the start of this buffer that are 0xAAAA. My initial reaction is to add a Header_length constant and then add Header_length to the input to malloc. From that point I don't know how to assign a value to those two bytes.

Edit: The meat of the question is how do I assign the first two bits of the Messagebuffer within the initialization function.

One final question, if I want Buffer_start to be read out as an array of Char should I assign that point like so:

```
 Message_buffer -> Buffer_start = (char *)malloc(sizeof(Captured_data)*Elements);
```

This would mean I was allocating an array of Char of size (sizeof(Captured_data*Elements). Then use memcpy to load values directly into buffer based on what Buffer_current is pointing to.

Comment: I am not sure that I get what your question is.

Comment: My question is how do I assign the first two bytes of the space allocated in with the malloc within an allocation function. So the data should be Bytes 0 and 1: Header Data then Byte 2: Is pointed to by Buffer Current

Comment: Just asign them after `malloc()`ing the memory.

Comment: something like *Buffer_start = A  and *(Buffer_start+1) = A. I am really unsure of the correct method to assign the values. I would assume I would want to create a point to a char at address Buffer_start. Assign the first one then add one and assign the second.